# Node is getting [object Object] from the client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending some data via Form Data

```
const fd = new FormData();
if(data){
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     fd.append('images', data[i]);
  }
}
await this.$axios.put(`/product/${state.details._id}`, fd);
```

On the server (i am using Node js) i am getting the following format of data

```
[ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]
```

I tried to parse it via JSON.pasre(), but with no success. Any suggestions on what is going on?

Comment: Out of question, but there is libraries like ```express-file-upload``` for express or ```multer``` for general usage, which they can handle your file upload and make separation of body and files in your request object.

Comment: Are you using expressJS with node ?

Comment: I am using multer. But the problem is when I updating the product with images and the quantity of images decreases from 4 to 3 for example. In req.body.images there is this format [object Object]. But when I am adding new images they are available via req.files['images'] and in normal format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
fd.append('images', JSON.stringify(data[i]));
```